# Google OpenSSL's Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, android-security

i have received google warning related to OpenSSL version update and provided linux based command **"$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"** to check OpenSSL version. I have tried cygwin and other tools but unable unable to execute this command on Windows 10.
 Is their any other way to find OpenSSL version on windows?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Super User exists to help you with commands.

Comment: if you are using cygwin, make sure to intall the "unzip" program from the cygwin installer